flutter cannot see emulators wrong .android file location
when I use the command flutter doctor -v all seems fine
when I list the emulators or devices I get no emulators I create an emulator it is not
listed.

still no emulators
when I open android studio the device is created but not listed in the flutter when I use the command flutter emulators.

The sdk manage location is not the problem it is listed in the correct location on android
and in android-studio and flutter doctor it is the same the .android file however is in ~/.config/.android for me but I think flutter is looking for it in ./android
I want to configure flutter to use the ~./config'android instead of
I have read the docs about config flutter but all it speaks about is changing the android/sdk path in flutter nothing about the .android
path file.
note: I am using a Debian Linux machine

can you post the output of flutter -v devices command?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Lb4c9oL-8UM2M-gBZsGYUDGja4aw3sNS/view?usp=sharing

I am very sorry about that I did not read you comment properly my brain read devices as doctor
https://drive.google.com/file/d/15GNr51h2HBxI9kqquXq2zqFef1Tfm9Tl/view?usp=sharing

it says it found emulator-5554 - do you have such a device?

I did create it but I removed it from the android studio virtual devices screen so no I do not have it
